# SourceTree で GitHub からのクローンができない

Tags: github, sourcetree

SourceTreeでGitHubのアカウントの認証を成功させた後に、HTTPS経由でクローンを行おうと思いました。
画像のように、ログイン画面が複数現れ、全てに入力してもクローンができませんでした。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

心当たりのある方はよろしくお願いします。

バージョン
windows10
SourceTree Version 2.3.1.0

Comment: リンク先と同じ問題であれば、リンク先の手順で解決するかもしれませんね。 https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Sourcetree-2-3-1-0-fail-to-authenticate-to-an-enterprise/qaq-p/643359

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git

の Windows 版の 対応方法にあるように

スタートメニューから「資格情報マネージャー」を検索して、開いて
その 「Windows 資格情報」の中にある GitHub に関連しそうな URL のキャッシュを消してみてはどうでしょうか？

また、コマンドプロンプトでは clone できているのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

ツール→オプション→認証のタブにGithubの登録はありますか？
登録がないようでしたら、ここへ先に認証を追加してみてはどうでしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。認証のタブにGithubの登録は追加はしてあります。しかし、上記のような症状が出ております。

Comment: ごめんなさい、一番最初に書いてありましたね。わたしの環境だと、SourceTree 2.5.5.0なのですが、最新版にしてみて改善するでしょうか？